# Setting up a server that allows any client to connect

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I have recently starting researching networking, so I am new with these topics. I have been trying to setup a server that would allow a client to connect to regardless of their location. I searched the web and was able to code a basic echo server and client using the python library sockets. However, I am unsure of what to do next in order to allow any client to connect to my server.

I researched static IP addresses but since I am in college and do not have admin access to the router I was unable to create an address.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are more secured to use in your local network which allows you to connect a client with a server according to the computer's local network's IP address (for example, one computer's IP address can be 192.168.1.35 and another computer's IP address can be 192.168.1.96). When you want to connect a client with a server that are not under the same network it's a bit more problematic because you need to get through the firewall and it could be dangerous. I advise you to first write a code of a client and a server that works and to understand how to data is being transferred between them and then to take it up to the next level. If you want I have some basic Python socket codes I can add here if you need.

**CODES:**

### server.py

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 20000))
server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)
what_to_send = 'Hello ' + client_name.decode()
client_socket.send(what_to_send.encode())
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

### client.py

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 20000))
name = input("Enter your name: ")
my_socket.send(name.encode())
data = my_socket.recv(1024)
print(data.decode())
my_socket.close()
```

**NOTE**: the port 20000 was chosen randomly, no specific reason, although you should read about ports (to not get off topic I'll say that the port range is 1024-65535). Moreover, On the client.py file the IP address "127.0.0.1" means that the server you want to connect to is running on the same machine, on the same computer. That means that the code here with this specific IP address is working only when you run the server and the client on the same computer.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I will start coding a client and server to start with the basics. If you can upload those examples that would be a huge help.

Comment: I added the codes for you to use. If you have any more questions you can ask and I'll try to come up with an answer. @Ncampy